# Proper use of Get-Childitem with a PowerShell Foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I want to take a text file with usernames, and then search a specific location ([UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path) and return any matches found, outputting them to a log file:

```
#Searches target folder for all folders matching input

$start = (get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
$defaultLogFileName = "folder_matcher" + $start + ".log"

#Log file header

$header = @()
$header += "=============================="
$header += "Search results"
$header += ""
$header += "Execution Start: " + (get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d %H%M") + ""
$header += ""

#Get the logfile location
do
{
    $logdir = Read-Host "Enter log directory (or press Enter for default c:\)"
    if ($logdir -eq "")
        {$logfile = ("c:\" + $defaultLogFileName); break;}
    if(Test-Path $logdir)
        {$logfile += ($logdir + "\" + $defaultLogFileName); break;}
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Directory does not exist"
} while (!(Test-Path $logfile))

$SourceFile = Read-Host "Enter file path"
$SearchValue = Read-host "Enter target directory to sweep"

$header | Out-File -FilePath $logfile

foreach($user in $sourcefile){
    Get-ChildItem $SearchValue -filter $user | Out-file -Append -FilePath $logfile
}
```

When I attempt to use [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) in this loop, this is the result:

```
Get-ChildItem : Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.
Parameter name: path2
At \\erebus\erebus_users$\rraymond1\ps\searchandmatch.ps1:32 char:14
+ Get-ChildItem <<<<  $SearchValue -filter $user | Out-file -Append -FilePath $logfile
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\harvard\tsprofiles$:String)
[Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId  DirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I have tried replacing the variables with fixed values (even mapping the UNC path locally and trying to run it that way), and the problem remains. How can I fix it?

Comment: I've just solved this myself - the issue was my understanding of the ForEach and what it can and cannot do. I thought it was capable of performing the functions of Get-Content by itself. All I had to do was add a new line:
    $Users = Get-Content $SourceFile

And change the loop to: 
    foreach($user in $users)

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question.

Comment: Once you have 15 reputation, you can answer your own question and accept it.